# Retrive different thumb dimension from BoxClient [Box.com JavaSDK]

Tags: java, thumbnails, box-api, boxapiv2

This code retrive correctly the 32x32 thumbnail of the file:

```
BoxClient boxClient = getBoxClient();
BoxThumbnail thumb = boxClient.getFilesManager().getThumbnail(assetId, "png", null);
```

But what if I want to get the 128x128 or 256x256 thumb?
I cannot found the param or a method to retrive this thumb.

Is there any magic tricks that I can do in order to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of passing that null at the end, create a BoxImageRequestObject

```
BoxClient boxClient = getBoxClient();
BoxImageRequestObject requestObject = new BoxImageRequestObject();
requestObject.setMinWidth(255);
BoxThumbnail thumb = boxClient.getFilesManager().getThumbnail(assetId, "png", null);
```